# C Filling 2 Dimensional Array

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am working on a c project. I need to fill this array with numbers. but when I try something like this it gives segmentation error. what is your suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int **my2DArray;

  my2DArray = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));

  for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    my2DArray[i] = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
  }

  for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++) {
      my2DArray[i][j] = 1;
    }
  }

  for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++) {
      printf("%d", my2DArray[i][j]);
    }
  }

  for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    // error happens here
    free(my2DArray[i]); 
  }

  free(my2DArray);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `malloc(4*sizeof(int));` -> `malloc(4*sizeof(int*));`

Comment: Thats no 2d array but a jagged array. Don't do something like that. Use one dimension and project x-dimensional indexes on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it gives segmentation error.

`sizeof(int)` is not the size of the type pointed to by `int **my2DArray`.
 `my2DArray` is a [pointer to pointer to int](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+**my2DArray) and thus points to a `int *`.
Likely on OP's platform an `int` is smaller than a `int*`.

> what is your suggestions?

Rather than spend effort coding the matching type (and potentially get it wrong), size to the de-referenced pointer.  It is easier to code right, review and maintain.

```
int **my2DArray;

// my2DArray = malloc(4*sizeof(int));
my2DArray = malloc(sizeof *my2DArray * 4);  // no type needed
//                 ^---------------^        // Size of the de-referenced type
```

Robust code would detect allocation failures

```
my2DArray = malloc(sizeof *my2DArray * element_count);
if (my2DArray == NULL && element_count > 0) {
  // Handle out-of-memory in some fashion
  fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory\n");
  exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```